# What does this compiler message (vectorization, GCC) means?

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization

Using GCC 4.8.1 on previous generation i7 processor with flags:

```
 -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5  -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -fno-operator-names -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffast-math
```

(e.g. all of 'hem!)

I get:

```
.cpp:31:note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: D.56044_367 = __builtin_logf (D.55726_232);
```

for the line:

```
for(i=0;i<N5;i++)   d3[i]=std::log(d2[i]);
```

what does this 'error' message mean? (d3 and d2 are vector of floats). Is it hopeless to vectorize the log function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `vectorize` means to pack multiple data items into one register and to operate on them in parallel using `vector` (a.k.a. `packed`) instructions.  Many floating point operations have `vector` forms, `LOG` is not one of them.  Here's a list of single-precision packed form vector instructions, from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/epmoa/index.html

- **ADDPS** add packed single-precision floating-point values
- **DIVPS** divide packed single-precision floating-point values
- **MAXPS** return maximum packed single-precision floating-point values
- **MINPS** return minimum packed single-precision floating-point values
- **MULPS** multiply packed single-precision floating-point values
- **RCPPS** compute reciprocals of packed single-precision floating-point values
- **RSQRTPS** compute reciprocals of square roots of packed single-precision floating-point values
- **SQRTPS** compute square roots of packed single-precision floating-point values
- **SUBPS** subtract packed single-precision floating-point values

Comment: quick question: would you know if ICC would be able to vectorize the log()?

Comment: Probably not, but here's some open source that does that for you: http://code.google.com/p/fastapprox/

Answer (score 1):

It means that compiler has no SIMD (SSE) instructions to evaluate log.

SIMD instructions allow to evaluate several operations for the price of one so to speak.
Log and its relatives typically have no matching hardware instructions.